# Meaning of done function kriskowal's q

Tags: javascript, q

The done function is used to end a chain of promises, like:

```
foo()
.then(function () {
    return "bar";
})
.done();
```

From the project link: https://github.com/kriskowal/q:

> When you get to the end of a chain of promises, you should either return the last promise or end the chain.

What exactly does "end the chain" mean? What are the implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site has a great explanation

http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/

Here is the text under the topic:  ***done() to the Rescue***

> done() can be called whenever then() can. The key differences are it
>   does not return a promise, and any unhandled exception inside of
>   done() is not captured by the promise implementation. In other words,
>   done() represents when the entire promise chain has fully resolved.

And the code example used in the site's example.

```
 getSomeJson().done(function(json) {
  // when this throws, it won't be swallowed
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Further reading from q's github
https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress